# What could be practical case where in I need to use interrupt method in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading

What could be practical case where in I need to use interrupt method in JAVA ?

Comment: If You ask - probably don't need

Answer (score 3):

There are some of examples, most involve the intend to shut a thread down. You need it if you want to **interrupt a Thread** ([documentation of Thread#interrupt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt())).

---

One example could be that an **exception** occurred, something **abnormal** to the **regular execution**. You want the thread to immediately listen and **handle the new situation**.

Or if you want to **shutdown a thread**. Then you might use interrupt to ensure that the thread reacts to your shutdown call and does not continue sleeping for some seconds or so.

Or imagine an application that installs a program which takes about 10 minutes. You may want to have a **cancel button** which aborts the installation process. The method assigned to that button may then use `interrupt` under the hood to ensure that the process cancels in time.

---

If we break it down then its just a regular **flag** that can be set and checked. You set it with `Thread#interrupt` and check it by `Thread#isInterrupted`.

There are multiple methods in the Java library that already use this flag, like `Thread#sleep` which throws an `InterruptedException` if the flag was set while sleeping.

---

Here is a small showcase as example:

```
public class Waiter extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean mShouldStop = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!this.mShouldStop) {
            System.out.println("Still there!");

            try {
                // Sleep for 10 seconds
                Thread.sleep(10_000);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                // Abort sleeping, got interrupted.
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Shutting down!");
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        this.mShouldStop = true;
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Create and start the thread
        final Waiter waiter = new Waiter();
        System.out.println("Start");
        waiter.start();

        // Wait some seconds
        Thread.sleep(25_000);

        // Stop the thread, use interrupt to wake it up in case it slept
        System.out.println("Kindly ask for shutdown");
        waiter.shutdown();

        System.out.println("Interrupt it");
        waiter.interrupt();
    }
}
```

**Without** the interrupt the thread would react to the shutdown call only **after finishing sleeping**, so another 5 seconds would be necessary.

As a note: The `volatile` keyword ensures that, after a thread changes the object, all threads will fetch the updated variant and not work on older cached variants.

Comment: The `mShouldStop` variable has to be declared as `volatile`! (Beyond that, a convincing answer, +1. You may want to add the "High-Level" use case: Some computation is running, which will take 10 minutes, and the GUI shows a progress bar. It's always nice to have a "Cancel" button in this case. This button may then be implemented by calling `interrupt` under the hood)

Comment: Good idea, will include that.

Comment: This is in general the right idea. But the example is not good.

Comment: You may edit the answer and include a better example, or both together.